# Salesforce - Immortal access token

Tags: salesforce, access-token

I am trying to integrate Salesforce REST api into the contact form on our website.

Basically, whenever a person submits a contact form, a record in salesforce is created. I got it work but only with the token obtained via login request.

As sending two requests to handle a contact form is too much, I am looking for something long-lived that I can put directly to the code as static value. Does Salesforce support this kind of access token?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an accesstoken/sessionId that doesn't expire at some point in time.

Depending on the frequency of the calls, I'll typically hold onto the last valid session Id and use that until Salesforce indicates it has expired. At which point I'll do a one off process to establish a current session Id.

You could get a [refreshtoken via an OAuth flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm) and then use that to reestablish a a session as required. The [JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0) is also an option.

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer